# Searching for two resource types and sorting according to date?

Tags: hl7-fhir

Is it possible with a FHIR search procedure to search for TWO resource types and sort them according to the date? I'd like a list of Observation and QuestionnareResponses, in a single response, returning the newest 10 regardless of resource type.

Searching for one would be:

http://apps.ehelselab.com/baseDstu2/Observation?_sort:desc=date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any query using the standard "search" capability is always against exactly one resource type.  You can include referencing and referenced resources, but filtering and sorting are always done against the "base" resource for the search.  To do what you're interested in doing, you have a few options:

1. define a custom query using the OperationDefinition mechanism (only works if you've got a direct relationship between client and server systems so you can ensure all participants support the operation
2. Use a "Batch" to execute queries against both, then interpolate the results as you page through both result sets
3. You can do a query just on the "base", however there isn't presently a way to constrain the types of resources returned - you'd need a custom search criteria
4. You *might* be able to use the _filter mechanism - I haven't dived into it very deeply.  But I suspect that it also uses the "single target resource type" approach.

The best bet is probably #3.  If you submit a request to add a search criteria to "Resource" allowing constraining the resource type, that would probably let you do what you wanted.